# CiviEvent 4.7.7 Issue with Repeating Event

Tags: civievent, 4.7

I cannot find any reference to this issue in 4.7.7 mentioned here. My "Repeat Event" tab appears different than in test - with additional options.

Situation: As expected, there should be an enforced error check between radio buttons "Repeat On" and "Repeat By". Repeat On is once a week or once a month or year, or whatever day you select. Repeat By could be the 1st of each month, the First Sunday of every month, etc. The two options (Repeat On and Repeat By) are mutually exclusive.

HOWEVER - the error check is looking at the two options *within* *"Repeat By"* and ignoring the fact that Repeat On is selected. It throws the error that I must select one option (see attached pic) in what appears to be the Repeat By section. [image: Option Error]

There is not an option in Repeats By for "Every" - only specified regular intervals excluding weekly. Options are First, Second, Third, Fourth, Last. No option for EVERY.

FURTHER - when I select "Repeat By" and hit Save, despite what appears to be a successful save, IT IS NOT SAVED. No errors. No repeating event confirmation. And the tab is cleared [image: Post Save Image]

The behavior I expect is that I can select Repeat Every 1 Week Repeats On Sunday Ends On or After.

Or am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I wasn't able to recreate this error on the demo site (4.7.8), or on our installation. I also couldn't see an issue related to this in JIRA.

It looks like the JavaScript that conditionally displays those settings fields isn't working correctly on your site. You could check your JavaScript errors console to see if any problems are coming up.

Eg: in Chrome, press F12, go to the 'console' and then reload the settings page and try to make your changes.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will work through it on my side. Appreciate your help.

Comment: I have tried using your suggestions. Have updated everything (Java, Chrome, Safari, FF) to latest versions. Still fails to setup a recurring / repeating event.  (BTW - F12 doesn't load the JavaScript console on a Mac. I didn't make that clear.) Is it possible that since we do not have Cron running on the server that it would affect the repeating event setup?

Comment: Javascript error:
crm.designerapp.js?r=p3Sqe:11 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Application' of undefined(anonymous function) @ crm.designerapp.js?r=p3Sqe:11j @ jquery.js:3148k.fireWith @ jquery.js:3260m.extend.ready @ jquery.js:3472J @ jquery.js:3503

Comment: That's the JS error that's killing it then. Maybe post that error into your original question?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to test this in 4.7.9.  It became quickly obvious that 4.7.7 has an issue with the repeating event setup. The screens/options are NOT the same between the two versions.
(Note the version numbers at the bottom of the screenshots.)
[image]
[image]