# Backbone javascript conflict causing Configure Event / Repeat to fail

Tags: civievent, javascript, backbone

Problem with a Civi 4.7 installation on WordPress 4.7.2 -- due to other complications involving Backbone, we are NOT running JetPack.

I found a related question in [CiviEvent 4.7.7 Issue with Repeating Event](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/11933/civievent-4-7-7-issue-with-repeating-event) while trying to discern why the Repeat tab in Event Configuration fails to behave as it should. Specifically, I'm unable to make an event repeat weekly. User has selected a Repeat-every value (e.g. Tuesday). Instead of verifying that either a Repeat-every value or a Repeat-by value was selected, the javascript requires user to select one of the Repeat-by values -- which it obviously shouldn't. And even when user has done this (pretending, for the sake of argument, that user does not want a weekly repetition), the Save button simply clears the form. No error messages appear, but the Chrome javascript console shows four Uncaught Type errors on the page, of which three are in Backbone:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Application' of undefined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (crm.designerapp.js:11)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.min.js:2)
backbone.collectionsubset.js:225 Uncaught TypeError: Backbone.CollectionSubset is not a constructor
    at child.Backbone.Collection.subcollection (backbone.collectionsubset.js:225)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (jquery.crmProfileSelector.js:34)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at m.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at m.fn.init.$.fn.crmProfileSelector (jquery.crmProfileSelector.js:25)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (jquery.crmProfileSelector.js:89)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at m.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (jquery.crmProfileSelector.js:88)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:4)
backbone.collectionsubset.js:225 Uncaught TypeError: Backbone.CollectionSubset is not a constructor
    at child.Backbone.Collection.subcollection (backbone.collectionsubset.js:225)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (jquery.crmProfileSelector.js:34)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at m.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at m.fn.init.$.fn.crmProfileSelector (jquery.crmProfileSelector.js:25)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (jquery.crmProfileSelector.js:89)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at m.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (jquery.crmProfileSelector.js:88)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:4)
backbone.collectionsubset.js:225 Uncaught TypeError: Backbone.CollectionSubset is not a constructor
    at child.Backbone.Collection.subcollection (backbone.collectionsubset.js:225)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (jquery.crmProfileSelector.js:34)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at m.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at m.fn.init.$.fn.crmProfileSelector (jquery.crmProfileSelector.js:25)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (jquery.crmProfileSelector.js:89)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at m.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (jquery.crmProfileSelector.js:88)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:4)`

So my question is this. **How do I get this working properly in Civi 4.7.16?**

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of this is that civi uses backbone.js, but not in no-conflict mode. There is an issue open at https://issues.civicrm.org  for this. Once that issue is resolved, this plugin will start to work.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone new is having this problem, the solution is to upgrade to CiviCRM 4.7.31+. CiviCRM ships with the BackboneJS library; so do certain WordPress themes. Sometimes that causes a conflict. Conflict mitigation was added in 4.7.31.

Comment: I'm running into this problem on a Joomla site running 5.2.1 (along with other javascript errors - profile select dropdown not displaying...) (no Google extensions installed) :/

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

**Analytify - Google Analytics Dashboard** (for WordPress) v. 2.0.13 by WPBrigade. Soon as that one was disabled, Repeat Events worked right as rain.

Now to find a usable Analytics plugin for WP 4.7 …