# Updating Repeated CiviEvents in 4.7 and 5.0

Tags: civievent, repeating-events

Having an issue updating details of recurring events.

This is happening on a clients site (was happening in 4.7 versions and still occuring after upgrade to 5.0)

Have just recreated issue on sand box

1) Create event with 12 weekly repeats
2) Add event custom data
3) I can update the custom fields in one event instance, and get the dialog box to update all/ future events. If I select to update all events I get a confirmation notice that the event has been updated. But when I look at future events the changes haven't been saved there only on the event instance editted.

Has anyone seen anything like this before? Know of a quick fix

Not sure if it's related to issues raised here or not
[Backbone javascript conflict causing Configure Event / Repeat to fail](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/17514/backbone-javascript-conflict-causing-configure-event-repeat-to-fail)

Conversely, when they set the event each session had a £20 session fee. They want one session to have a £25 session fee.

When they update the specific session fee tab and select update only this event, on saving fees for all events are updated.

I've  been able to recreate that in sandbox also. Add a fee for the first event instance, and create recurring events.

Updating a fee in a later event instance, and saving this event only updates fees for all instances.

The client was using repeat events in their 4.6 install, and apparently these features worked fine. I've not used repeat events myself that much so have no experience prior to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can assure you that custom fields never carried over to repeating events in Civi 4.6 - I had to write a lot of custom code to deal with the fact!

The issue you're describing is [CRM-16902](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16902).  It's marked as closed, but that's incorrect - a related issue, [CRM-20787](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20787) was recently fixed.

Before CRM-20787 was merged, it WAS possible to change a single price on a repeating event.  This might be the changed behavior your client is noticing.  If selecting "this event only" isn't possible now, that's a regression and should be reported.

That said - dealing with price changes and price sets is very thorny.  If I change event 3 (only) to have a different price, then I change a different event's price and say "change all events" - does event 3 have the new price?  Or just the unchanged events?

In short - it's not a quick fix.  It needs code to be written.